# if/elseif statement not working as expected in PS

Tags: windows, powershell

I have created a If/ElseIf statement to determine whether the computer is in a certain domain or not, however for some reason this is not working:

```
#Detect whether the script is running on a company1 or company2 device
$FQDN = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain();
If ($FQDN -eq "example.company1.com"){
$OU = "OU=Company Computers,DC=company,DC=com"
}
ElseIf ($FQDN -eq "example.company2.com"){
$OU = "OU=Workstations,OU=NL,DC=company,DC=com"
}
Else{
write-host "Unfortunately you are not on a company1 or company2 domain joined device, this script will exit now."
pause
return
}
```

When running this on a device which is part of example.company1.com, It comes back with "Unfortunately you are not on a copmany1 or company2 domain joined device, this script will exit now."
As a troubleshooting step I printed `$FQDN`, which  nicely shows `example.company1.com`, so that part seems to work fine. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I think that the return value of `GetCurrentDomain()` is an object, not a string and that you have to access the `Name` property first before you can compare it. Like: `If ($FQDN.Name -eq "example.company1.com")`.

Comment: I feel soo stupid now, thanks a million, this works.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will add my comment as an answer. Glad I could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `GetCurrentDomain()` is an **object**, not a string, you have to access the Name property first before you can compare it:

```
#Detect whether the script is running on a company1 or company2 device
$FQDN = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain();
If ($FQDN.Name -eq "example.company1.com") {
    $OU = "OU=Company Computers,DC=company,DC=com"
}
ElseIf ($FQDN.Name -eq "example.company2.com") {
    $OU = "OU=Workstations,OU=NL,DC=company,DC=com"
}
Else {
    write-host "Unfortunately you are not on a company1 or company2 domain joined device, this script will exit now."
    pause
    return
}
```